# Set a specific session timeout for specific sessions

Tags: php, session

I want to set a specific session timeout for specific sessions in the admin panel without affecting the session timeouts of the sessions in the site

I have searched already for answers but all of them affects all of the sessions (not just specific sessions)

Here are the sessions I want to have a specific timeout:

```
$_SESSION["user_id"]);
$_SESSION["user_first_name"];
$_SESSION["user_last_name"];
$_SESSION["user_email"];
$_SESSION["user_type"];
$_SESSION["user_profile_picture"];
```

Comment: set a time as a session variable, check that as required and kill it when that expires.

Comment: They aren't sessions, they are session variables, which are stored in a single session

Comment: I see. Is there a way to set their session timeout without affecting the sessions of the site?